# Why I am always Getting Device.isNormal() even on mobile

Tags: spring-boot, responsive-design

I am using `org.springframework.mobile.device.Device` in my `Spring Boot` application. The problem is that, even if I use a mobile Device, it still returns Device type as `Normal` or `Desktop`. Below is the code I am using:

```
@PostMapping(value="/")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> detectDevice(Device device) {
        DeviceType deviceType = DeviceType.DESKTOP_DEVICE;
        if (device.isMobile()) {
            deviceType = DeviceType.MOBILE_DEVICE;
        } else if (device.isTablet()) {
            deviceType = DeviceType.TABLET_DEVICE;
        }
       //other statements
}
```

I have added dependency as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-mobile.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And in my `application.properties` file, I have added this line:

```
spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.enabled=true
```

**Also** please tell me if I could check this functionality from my browser's console by going into mobile view.

Comment: You are aware that Spring Mobile isn't officially maintained anymore and that newer browsers and devices might not even be detected anymore.

Comment: Oh I see. So do you know a similar technique or any alternative method to do that now?

Comment: @M.Deinum sir do you know any alternative way to do so.... Kindly suggest me....